# Allocation/Allotment algorithm

Tags: python, allocation

I'm trying to share 8 balls with 4 people in the table below. Column 1,2,3 is the order of demand for the balls. For example, Mike prefers ball-A primarily.

Name    1   2   3

Mike:   A   B   C

John:   A   B   -

David:  B   A   -

Alex:   A   C   -

Another example, There are 4 A and 4 C balls in total.(no B) If we distribute these 8 balls by manually, it should be like this;

Mike    C   C

John    A   A

David   A   A

Alex    C   C

Despite the ball-C is Mike's 3rd choice, he must select it  two times. Because if he selects ball-A then John or David cannot select any ball.

I hope I could tell my problem with my terrible English :)

Is there an example of an algorithm you would suggest to solve this problem?
Thanx.

Comment: This sounds like a constraint solving problem. I think linear programming is a technique that's usually used for this.

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem. What code did you try?